# How to make appendices like section in bookmarks

Tags: hyperref, appendices, bookmarks

I had a problem as I wanted to make my appendices look like sections.

I already found a solution to do this for the table of contents by using this code just before the `\chapter` command in the appendix environment :

```
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
\makeatother
```

Now, I would like to make the bookmarks "realize" it. When I open the PDF file the Appendices appears at a chapter level, but the title of the appendix appears at chapter level too.

All the bookmarks I have come from the `hyperref` package, so I guess I can't use the `bookmark` package to find a solution.

Is there any way to make it look like a section of the chapter Appendices in the bookmarks?

Here is the code I use in my LaTeX program:

```
\begin{appendices}
 \makeatletter
 \addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
 \makeatother
 \chapter{Appendix1}
 \chapter{Appendix2}
 ...
 \end{appendices}
```

I already tried to use the `\section` function instead of `\chapter`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7):

### Method via `\bookmarksetupnext`

With package `bookmark` the following is possible:

```
\bookmarksetupnext{level=-1}
\addappheadtotoc
```

overwrites the bookmark setting of "Appendices" and moves it a level higher to part level. Then the appendix chapters become children to the "part" appendices.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{A chapter}
  \section{A section}
  \chapter{Another chapter}
  \section{A section}
  \begin{appendices}
    \bookmarksetupnext{level=-1}
    \addappheadtotoc
    \makeatletter
    \addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
    \makeatother
    \chapter{Appendix1}
    \chapter{Appendix2}
     ...
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The example is based on the example in Werner's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84740/16967).

### Method via `\toclevel@<section>`

Package `hyperref` configures the bookmark levels in macros `\toclevel@chapter`, `\toclevel@section`:

```
...
\def\toclevel@chapter{0}
\def\toclevel@section{1}
\def\toclevel@subsection{2}
\def\toclevel@subsubsection{3}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{4}
\def\toclevel@subparagraph{5}
...
```

These macros can be redefined:

```
\begin{appendices}
  \makeatletter
  \addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
  \def\toclevel@chapter{1}
  \def\toclevel@section{2}
  \def\toclevel@subsection{3}
  % ... (add deeper levels if needed)
  \makeatother
  \chapter{Appendix1}
  \chapter{Appendix2}
  ...
\end{appendices}
```

Remark: You can use package `bookmark` together with `hyperref` getting faster updated bookmarks and more features.

Comment: For me just putting `\bookmarksetupnext{level=-1}` above `\begin{appendices}` seems to work fine

Comment: Actually; apparently what I said does not affect the TOC, only the bookmarks

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you're after something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{appendix,bookmark,xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{appendix,bookmark,xpatch}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\section{A section}
\begin{appendices}
\makeatletter
\addappheadtotoc
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
% \xpatchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\xpatchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}{{toc}{chapter}}{{toc}{section}}{}{}%
\xpatchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}{{toc}{chapter}}{{toc}{section}}{}{}%
\makeatother
\chapter{Appendix1}
\chapter{Appendix2}
 ...
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The missing puzzle piece is provided by the [`xpatch` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch). It is used to patch the original `\@chapter` command, stored in `\Hy@org@chapter` (as defined by [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and/or [`bookmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark)).

In essence, the patch changes the ToC entry from `chapter` to `section`.

The solution works with both `hyperref` and `bookmark`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly for me, this is exactly what I was looking for.